# How to fix improper <pre> formatting in html on mobile device?

Tags: html, css, ascii, pre

I have some ascii art in an html file which is inside `<pre>` tags.
The text is shown properly in desktop with proper spacing but the formatting gets messed up when viewed on mobile.
I am using monospace font-family, tried changing to other fonts, but they had the same result.

Screenshots
Desktop : [webpage when viewed on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LGUZ.jpg)
Mobile : [webpage when viewed on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfLgh.png)

I've checked with Google chrome and Brave browser, both show the same result.

The page is hosted on [ankushKun.github.io](http://ankushKun.github.io/pages/connect-with-me.html) if someone wants to check it out themselves.

HTML : https://pastebin.com/E89hmN3i 
CSS : https://pastebin.com/pkuURxsQ 
The html page uses javascript to load additional html from a .txt file, this text file contains the ascii art. Any html tag having `include-html="file-path"` will be replaced with the contents of that file.
TXT : https://pastebin.com/WkDTMNwJ

I have tried putting the ascii directly inside the .html page, but it has the same results, so it's not an issue with loading the txt file into html but something wrong with how the text is formatted on mobile I think.

e.g.

```
 ██████  ██ ████████ ██   ██ ██    ██ ██████ 
██       ██    ██    ██   ██ ██    ██ ██   ██
██   ███ ██    ██    ███████ ██    ██ ██████ 
██    ██ ██    ██    ██   ██ ██    ██ ██   ██
 ██████  ██    ██    ██   ██  ██████  ██████
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try connecting your phone to your PC browser so you can use [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/). My guess is that the generic `monospace` font on mobile handles some of those _block_ characters differently

Comment: Could you put a working snippet into your question, perhaps showing just one of the words that turns out wrong on mobile. And is it mobile (if so, which ones) or narrow viewports that cause the problem?

Comment: Your site works OK on IOS Safari (iPad) so is it Android that has the problem?

Comment: @AHaworth I have edited the question and added an example ascii that turns out wrong on mobile. Not sure if it's an android thing since I don't have any device with iOS for testing

Comment: @Phil Yeah you're right, I used a different ascii art, one with some blocky character instead of spaces and now it appears correctly on mobile, however when I replace that with a space, it goes back to being weirdly formatted. Anyways, this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers, the issue was with the ASCII ART that I used, which was being rendered improperly on android, just change the ASCII to something else and check if it renders properly

Answer (score 0):

One way can be [measure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) your `pre` and if it wider then [screen width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width) use `css` [transform to scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale()) it.

```js
let art = document.querySelectorAll('pre')[0];
let artWidth = window.getComputedStyle(art).getPropertyValue('width');
if (window.screen.width < parseFloat(artWidth)) {
  art.setAttribute('style', 'transform: scale(0.5)');
}
```

```html
<pre>
 ██████  ██ ████████ ██   ██ ██    ██ ██████ 
██       ██    ██    ██   ██ ██    ██ ██   ██
██   ███ ██    ██    ███████ ██    ██ ██████ 
██    ██ ██    ██    ██   ██ ██    ██ ██   ██
 ██████  ██    ██    ██   ██  ██████  ██████ 
</pre>
```